# get set (list of distinct values) that satisfy condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I got documents of products. product looks like:

```
{
   "_index": "1",
   "_type": "product", 
   "_id": "1",
   "_source": {
      "group": "g1"
      "exist": true 
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of groups (of all products) - but only these how satisfy `"exist" == true` (group that has at least one existing product)

I've tried:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs" : {
       "_source" : {
           "terms" : { 
             "field" : "group"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

which return list of groups with their count (which is also redundant and might cost extra time to calc) but I'm trying to add the condition/query of `"exist"=true`.

1. How can I achieve that?
2. Do I really need aggregation for it? (is there more efficient way?)

Note: I'm using elastic search 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Adding [Filtered aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to the terms aggregation would ensure only groups with exist `true` show up.
To improve performance ensure "group" field is not "analyzed"

Example:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "exist_group": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "exist": "true"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "groups": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "group"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: that's return the group list, but also count it - which is redundant work. I have thousands of documents and it took too much time. I wonder if there is a way without counting (I found `cardinality` but it just returns the number of distinct groups without showing them)

Comment: my guess is the actual overhead of counting shouldn't be significant since doc-frequency of term would be calculated at indexing. To improve performance ensure "group" field is not "analyzed"

Comment: if there are still issues with performance and you probably could look into perloading the fielddata or using ordinals if the "group" fields has few distinct terms . This document preloading the fielddata has useful tips – keety